# Java: classes with instance of each other

Tags: java

I feel like this is a really basic question, but I've never got a situation like this. Right now I have a structure like this:

```
public class Main{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
}
```

My `ClassA` is needed in `ClassB` as well as in the `Main.class`. Now I noticed that `ClassA` has to know `ClassB` as well.

```
public class Main{
    ClassA a = new ClassA(b);
    ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
}
```

Obviously won't work. First I thought of using a `Observer Pattern` but this seems to be an overkill to me, besides it's not what the pattern is usually used for. 
Is there a way, that I can make `Main.class` know `ClassA.class` & `ClassB.class`, as well as make `ClassA.class` know `ClassB.class` and vice-versa? Since `Main.class` uses `ClassA` as well I have to have the same class only initialized once.

Comment: Its a circular dependency which you should avoid

Comment: Why not assign it? Declare `b` first, then assign `a` to a variable in it. You don't necessarily have to put this in the constructor.

Comment: Like `Rehman` said, this is a guaranteed memory leak because the two objects will always point to each other, and unless one of them is explicitly set to `null`, neither will ever be garbage collected.

Comment: There are a couple of solutions to this. You should tell us a bit more about your use case so we can find out what makes sense the most.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set the references in the constructor. You can create a setter which you can call after you've created both objects such as `b.setA(a);`.

Comment: I feel almost stupid to forget this option... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can use a setter method

add to your `ClassA`:

```
public void setB(ClassB b) {
  this.b = b;
}
```

and then:

```
public class Main{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
    a.setB(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to create both a `ClassA` and a `ClassB` instance at once and pass them to each other's constructors.

What you could do is create a setter in `ClassA` to set the `ClassB` instance, which you call after creating both objects:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
b.setA(a);
```

However, the fact that you need to have two objects which refer to each other is a red flag with regard to the design of the classes. It means that the two classes are very tightly coupled, and in general you want [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

It's better if you could change the design of your classes so that you don't need a circular dependency like this. Maybe you should just make them one class, or you could add an additional class that represents the link between the `ClassA` and `ClassB` objects - for example a `ClassC` that holds the references to the `a` and `b` objects.

Which solution is appropriate depends on what you're doing exactly; it's hard to tell without more information about your actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the classes to know about each other but rather than `a` instance of `ClassA` to know about the `b` instance of `ClassB`.

In this case you could create a setter in `ClassA` and call it after the construction of `b`, or you can use *magic*. Some DI frameworks can implement said magic for you. One example of such masgic is to pass in a wrapper into the constructor of `ClassA` and set the wrapper to point to `b` post construction.

Finally you could look at your class structure. You currently have a *circular dependency* and they are generally bad things. Could `ClassA` and `ClassB` both be dependent on a new `ClassC` (which has no dependencies) for example?